# A finite field cannot be an ordered field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ordered-fields

I am reading [baby Rudin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007054235X) and it says all ordered fields with supremum property are isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Since all ordered  finite fields would have supremum property that must mean none exist. Could someone please show me a proof of this?

Thank you very much, Regards.

Comment: Do you know that in any ordered field the only possibility is $$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2=0\iff a_i=0\;\;?$$

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**HINT:** Suppose that $(F,0,1,+,\cdot,<)$ is an ordered field which is finite of characteristic $p$. Then $0<1<1+1<\ldots$, conclude a contradiction.

Comment: Which, alas, spoils the hint in my prior answer. Was that necessary?

Comment: Clear, short, accurate. +1

Comment: @Bill: It seems to me that your answer might be useful to someone tackling this from an algebraic point of view; not from the point of view of Baby Rudin.

Comment: @Asaf The OP tagged it abstract algebra, so I presumed they knew some algebra. But, in any case, most any Baby Rudin reader should be able to understand my hint that "positives are closed under addition", which is all that's needed to finish. You simply picked the simplest positive, $\,g=1.\ \ $

Comment: @Bill: Yes, I agree. But "Linearly ordered groups are torsion free" can be outright confusing to someone unfamiliar with these terms.

Comment: @Asaf Agreed, if one knows no group theory. Probably I should have said "positives are closed under addition" and later segued into the more general group-theoretical view, to avoid scaring away readers.

Comment: I found both answers useful, Asaf was more straight to the point and Bill was more profound, The only reason I accepted Asaf and not Bill's is it took me more time to understand what Bill said.

Comment: @user4140 Thanks for the feedback. I've incorporated Asaf's constructive critique (thanks!) and reordered my answer to put the more abstract remarks last.

Answer (score 19):

**Hint** $\ $ In an [ordered ring,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) positives are closed under addition (so a sum of positives is $\ne 0$).

**Remark** $\ $ More generally, note that [linearly ordered groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_ordered_group) are torsion-free: $\rm\: 0\ne n\in \mathbb N,$  $\rm\:g>0 \:\Rightarrow\: n\cdot g = g +\cdots + g > 0,\:$ since positives are closed under addition. Conversely, a torsion-free commutative group can be linearly ordered [(Levi, $1942$)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03174799).

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** any finite field must have a non-zero [characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29).